# Hide specific field of a table codeigniter, postgresql

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

As the title stated, can we hide a specific field of a table? Example i want to hide column 6, row 5. BTW Im using codeigniter, postgresql, php.

Answer (score 0):

If you are aware of jQuery try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#IdOfTable tr').eq(4).find('td').eq(5).css('visiblity','hidden');
      // hidding sixth column of fifth row at the time, your page is loaded
})
```

Edit :

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#IdOfTable tr').eq(4).find('td').eq(5).css('visiblity','hidden');
          // hidding sixth column of fifth row at the time, your page is loaded
    })

</script>
```

Comment: I guess you have jQuery included

Comment: I see. So can i use jQuery while using codeigniter,postgresql and php?

Comment: @Kino I have made an edit to inlcude jQuery google hosted lib. you can  use jquery in any webproject idealy

Comment: Thanks. I'll do what you said.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do that easily with CSS classes, for example:

```
.my-table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(4){
  display: none;
}
```

Using `nth-child` selector, you can make classes to hide as you see fit.